# Вставка фигурных скобок в код

Tags: c++, c, форматирование

Есть код на языках C и C++. Нужно автоматизированно вставить фигурные скобки (`{` , `}`) в код там, где их нет. К примеру:

```
if (a == 5)
    a++;
else
    a--;
```

должно стать:

```
if (a == 5)
{
    a++;
}
else
{
    a--;
}
```

Стиль, по которому вставляются скобки, не важен, главное их наличие. *Astyle* не предлагать, так как он не работает при большой вложенности.

Comment: Ну, не знаю даже, NetBeans, может быть, поможет. Alt-Shift-F - оформляет код.

Comment: На нем пересобирать проект. Плохое решение... Мне кажется, должно быть какое-то решение, что-то похожее на astyle, но с возможностью вставлять скобки по всему коду.